# Why does BJP want to know Rahul Gandhi's gotra?

Tags: india, religion

Why is the BJP so concerned about what caste and gotra Rahul Gandhi belong to? Every party in India claims to remove casteism but why does the BJP repeatedly bring up the caste and the religion of the opposition party leaders?

Source: https://www.ndtv.com/india-news/whats-your-gotra-sambit-patra-asks-as-rahul-gandhi-visits-temple-1939311

Answer (score 3):

> Why is the BJP so concerned about what caste Rahul Gandhi belongs to?

I find this question suprising when it was Congress Spokesperson, Randeep Singh Surjewala, who first, brought in the topic of Rahul Gandhi belonging to the Brahmin caste. From the article you quoted itself, it is clearly written that the BJP spokesperson Sambit Patra was speaking in response to Mr. Surjewala's statement:

> The comment is **linked to Congress leader Randeep Surjewala's pronouncement after Rahul Gandhi's visit to the Somnath temple in Gujarat that he is a "Janeu-dhari Brahmin"**.

So it was the Congress Party which brought in the topic of caste here first, not the BJP.

**Also, the term "gotra" doesn't mean caste. The correct term for "caste" is jati, not "gotra". The term "Gotra" refers to the lineage of the Saptarishis or the seven sages. People of different castes can have the same Gotra.**

> Every party in India claims to remove casteism but why does the BJP repeatedly bring up the caste and the religion of the opposition party leaders?

Really? No, that's completely a wrong statement. Just yesterday, we found a senior Brahmin Congress leader, in the state of Rajasthan making a [castiest statement against PM Modi](https://swarajyamag.com/insta/only-brahmins-can-speak-about-hindu-religion-not-low-caste-like-modi-uma-bharti-says-congress-leader-cp-joshi):

> **A senior Congress leader and key strategist of party president Rahul Gandhi, CP Joshi, waded into controversy as a leaked video in which he launched a vituperative casteist tirade against Prime Minister Narendra Modi, Union Minister Uma Bharathi and Sadhvi Ritambhara** went viral on social media.
>
> In a the video, **the Congress leader is seen disparaging the low-caste origin of Prime Minister Modi, Union Cabinet Minister Uma Bharti and Sadhvi Rithambara. He attacked them for talking about Hinduism and said that “only brahmins are learned enough to speak about Hinduism."**
>
> **“Does anyone know what is the caste of Uma Bharti? What is the caste of Sadhvi Ritambhara? In this country, if anyone knows about religion, it is the pandits and the brahmins," Joshi was heard saying in the video**.
>
> He added “It is strange that Uma Bharti, who is of the Lodh samaj is talking about Hindu religion, Sadhviji is of some religion/caste and she is talking about Hindu religion, Narendra Modiji is of some other religion/caste and he is talking about Hindus."

You can watch the complete video of C.P. Joshi  making this remark [here](https://twitter.com/sanghaviharsh/status/1065611960769806337?s=20). And this isn't a doctored video. C.P. Joshi himself has admitted  to having making this statement and apologised. This has exposed the castiest mentality of the Congress Party.

Other opposition parties such as DMK and BSP too have made similar castiest remarks in the past so your statement is completely wrong.

So why is the BJP spokesperson Sambit Patra asking Rahul Gandhi's Gotra?

Well, by asking Rahul Gandhi's gotra, BJP is asking evidence whether Rahul Gandhi indeed is a Hindu as he claims. There's already a doubt on the religion of Rajiv Gandhi. Conflicting claims of him being a Hindu, Zoroastrian and Muslim has been made over the years and so BJP is naturally exploiting this confusion.

Comment: I never for a moment said that Congress is not a casteist party. I just wanted to know that why BJP which calls itself different from the Congress want to know Mr Gandhi's caste/gotra? How will it make a difference what gotra Mr Gandhi belongs to?

Comment: @NiteeshShanbog You clearly said "Every party in India claims to remove casteism but why does the BJP repeatedly bring up the caste and the religion of the opposition party leaders". This clearly means BJP is the only castiest party to you.

Comment: And it was Randeep Singh Surjewala who brought the topic of Rahul Gandhi's caste. Why aren't you questioning him? @NiteeshShanbog

Comment: Please refer to my above comment. This question is not about every party in India.

Comment: This forum is not to debate about who is right or who is wrong. This forum is certainly not for whataboutery. My question was very specific. What will BJP do by knowing Mr Gandhi's caste/gotra?

Comment: @NiteeshShanbog It will indicate whether Rahul Gandhi is really a Hindu. And stop saying caste here. BJP didn't ask anything about caste here. They asked Rahul Gandhi's Gotra. Caste and Gotra aren't the same.

Comment: In a country having more than 70% Hindus, I don't understand why it is surprising that Rahul Gandhi is being portrayed as a 'Janeudhari Brahmin' and why the BJP is questioning it.

Answer (score -1):

Rahul Gandhi everytime as you know, he wants to introduce himself as shiva-bhakt or vishnu-bhakt or any to pose against people as a **Bhakta**. Because in India the religious matter is Apex in everything. So BJP is eagerly wanting to know his caste so that BJP can tell the Indian people that why Rahul Gandhi is doing this all the things because of publicity stunt or really he is that he introduces himself as Bhakta.

Comment: This does not answer the question. In fact, it creates more doubts. How will knowing his caste help in identifying his devotion to God, or his publicity seeking shenanigans?

Comment: Let me broaden my answer. Anyone don't know about the caste of Rahul Gandhi, I have already told that religious matter in India is Zenith. Now what caste Rahul Gandhi belongs that is controversy. If he is told Brahmin then from which clan and is he janoe-dhari or not, no one knows. If it is said that he is, then his impression would be good on the indians,its psychology as we know about religious character. But if BJP asks him to clarify the caste and if he fails to prove then it will not be better for him. I say only because of my perception,Nothing else

Comment: How can one prove one's caste?